# How to make the page number in a PDF file match with the one inbuilt in the app?

Tags: applications, google-apps, pdf

I have a PDF file, which shows page numbers after a few pages, like preface, index etc. However, I use the Drive PDF viewer, which starts counting pages from the preface page itself. Is there anyway, to make it start counting after a few pages, so that to match it with the book itself?

This maybe an off-site question, so instead of downvoting, please suggest me where else to post this question.

Comment: I'd direct that question to the developer of the app. There's nothing we can do about it, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

Three options

- **Splitting the PDF file**
- **Rearrange pages in PDF**
- Open the file on your [PC to edit](https://superuser.com/a/384935) and transfer it your Android - not tried by me

There are many apps , ( thanks to [Izzy](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_pdf))
that can do the first two options, but I would recommend [Xolo PDF reader and editor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xodo.pdf.reader) which is versatile in handling PDF files. Besides, you can export edited files to drive.

- *Deletion:*  You can delete those initial pages and export to drive or a different location in your device ( warning: make a copy of original file and use the copy to edit, since changes are permanent)
- *Rearrange pages:* Select and drag the pages you don't want ( for instance pages with Roman numbering and put them at the end of document ). Save and export to Drive or use Xolo. Note- This is a feature which is free in this app unlike a paid option in other apps

Comment: Apart from the app itself recognising, I was expecting manual setting of the page numbering.

Comment: Not clear. Are you saying that you expect Google drive to have manual settings of page numbers ( which is developer areas) or are you saying you are looking for an app that can do manual setting?

Comment: yeah, kinda both. Since automatic work will be a complicated process, giving us the option to do so still seems feasible.

Comment: [Coding to change page numbers is not for this site- but have a look](http://superuser.com/a/430628), let's leave that out.  Suggested another option. Just as FYI, the option to arrange pages is a paid option in [Adobe Acrobat Reader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adobe.reader) costing **1500 INR per month**. It's **free** in this app. Your choice to go the coding route, write to developer as Izzy suggested or delete the initial pages or rearrange them !!

Comment: @ReeshabhRanjan: surprised by your comment over coding. Is it clear now?

Comment: still figuring out what I am skipping. No? (Applies a silly helpless face)

Comment: I am genuinely trying to understand the difficulty, because the solution meets your needs fully, unless I misunderstood your needs. Can you start by explaining what is that exactly you don't understand?

Comment: I know you completely understand, but the link you gave gave lots of answers with coding involved. That's what I am saying.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47573/discussion-between-beeshyams-and-reeshabh-ranjan).